# keeping background class active

Tags: ios, swift, background

I have a storyboard that creates a 'crono' class to receive tcp data. I need this class to stay active (along with it's background receive thread) as different scenes register/unregister display objects with crono for real time updates to their UI objects when created/dismissed [Scene sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBPcE.png)

This works well in the sim but even when disabling the idle timer on the active scene, it appears that the scene or the instance of crono disappears due to user inactivity and crashes. What is the best way to create this static class so it remains active until I end the application?

Comment: Take a look at Singletons :) https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton it'll persist throughout the entire app life instead of being tied to the UI.

Comment: Looked like a solution at first glance but the iOS guidlines may make the app hard to get published

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing iOS Backgrounding Guidance, publishing an app with a bg task not related to a few key areas (voip, audio, location etc) could be problematic. Looks like the server application API will have to be changed to properly support iOS restrictions....